# Count How many zeroes in the inputed number?

Tags: c

Write a program that takes an integer and
prints the number of trailing zeroes.
Example:
Enter the number: 24100
Trailing zeroes: 2

I have no Idea what condition to create to determine the number of zeroes in a number.

Comment: Try as a human being. How can you tell that a number has a trailing zero? If you ask me for a number to process and I type in "1234", what do you as a human do to find out whether it has a trailing 0? Describe that in English. It is the first step of coming up with an algorithm.

Comment: And what if the number is 000240010? Do you want as an answer "Three leading zeroes, two inside zeroes and one trailing zero, total of six"? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a modulus trick here:

```c
int input = 24100;
int num_zeroes = 0;

while (input > 0) {
    if (input % 10 == 0) {
        num_zeroes = num_zeroes + 1;
        input = input / 10;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}

printf("%d", num_zeroes);  // 2
```

Comment: Why that clunky while-if-break, when a loop suffices?

Comment: Negative numbers can be even powers of 10, too... Jus' sayin'... (Try `input != 0`...)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I've upvoted your comment for an upvote :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Can you give an example of a negative number? Assuming you think of e.g. -10, which power of 10 results in -10? I think the value would be a complex one, with a non-zero imaginary part.

Comment: @Yunnosch 100 = 1 * 10^2 ... -100 = -1 * 10^2 ... I'd argue that both can be expressed as an "integer coeffiecient multiplying a power of 10."... Opinions may vary... `:)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 Sorry, power of 10 and trailing zeros are not the same anyway. I was nitpicking. Integer times power of 10 is fine.

Comment: @Yunnosch No worries... You helped me find and fix a bug in my answer... `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int cnt = 0; while( input && input % 10 == 0)  cnt++, input /= 10;
```

But, if you think you'll have access to SO when you are sitting the proficiency tests when applying for jobs, you are sadly mistaken.

Comment: I do not know, as far as I know the interviewers at the company I am working for cannot prevent applicants from using their smart phones during virtual job application meetings. They are however fiendishly good at interrupting them when they are and they check SO and other sites during the interview and they ask questions about code solutions which can only be answered by people actually understanding the code they give as answers. Quite nice actually. By the way, do you intentionally provide code which does not match the assignment? ;-) Also quite fiendish, setting such a "homework trap".

Comment: (removed the spoilers here...) Anybody actually testing your code will not notice (because they fix both issues, probably without being aware), but handing that in as a solution probably means a failure... Very subtle. I did not see what you mean by recursion and flash by the way; so maybe there are 4 issues in total.

Comment: @Yunnosch Fixed... Subtle indeed... ANOTHER dooser to add to the dossier... Thanks... "Recursion" is just a joke. Never mind... Thanks for the "heads-up", though...

Comment: :-) Did not spot what you edited either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247699/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-fe2o3).